# Comment on utilise "de" ou "au" avec des noms de plats?

Tags: prépositions

Je ne sais pas quand je dois utiliser "de" et "au" avec un nom de plat. Sur google j'ai trouvé des versions différentes.

p.e. Couscous de la mer/ de légumes/ de poison/ de poulet/ de manioc
 mais également Couscous au poulet, aux lardons et au boeuf

p.e.soupe au pistou/ aux chou/ au potiron/ au lait/ aux pois
mais également soupe de poisson/ de potiron/ de courgette/de courge/ de poulet.

Est-ce qu'il y a une règle quand on utilise "de" et quand "au"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il y a une règle ; lorsque le plat est constitué essentiellement de l'ingrédient nommé on utilise « **de** » ;

> soupe de poisson, soupe de légumes, soupe de poireaux, salade de pommes de terre, salade de laitue, rôti de bœuf, …

Lorsque l'ingrédient nommé n'entre dans le plat que comme un ingrédient supplémentaire, alors on utilise « **au** » ou « **à la** » si l'ingrédient est du féminin et qu'il ne constitue qu'un élément dans le plat (tarte aux fraises : il faut de nombreuses fraises; tarte à la crème : il n'y a qu'une crème; canard à l'orange : il s'agit de l'arome) ; donc on doit dire comme ci-dessous;

> couscous au poulet, couscous au mouton, couscous au bœuf (*parce que l'ingrédient essentiel dans le couscous consiste des grains de couscous et des légumes et que la viande ne  « définit » pas le plat*)
>  
>   tarte aux fraises, tarte aux quetsches, coq au vin, gâteau à la crème, dinde aux marrons, spaghettis à la sauce tomate, salade aux lardons, salade aux croutons, spaghettis à la sauce tomate, épinards à la (sauce) béchamel, …

Bien qu'il y ait cette règle il existe des exceptions nombreuses et assez peu compréhensibles comme  « soupe aux pois cassés » et « couscous de légume ».

Il existe par exemple une « soupe au chou » rustique qui consiste essentiellement de chou, mais le seul nom  utilisé est  « soupe au chou » ; il existe cependant une « soupe de chou-fleur à l'indienne ».

Answer (score 2):

Nota : Dans ta liste... *couscous de la mer* est un intrus...

Celui-là mis à part on pourra dire que l'on utilise "à, au, aux" quand ce qui suit n'est pas l'ingrédient principal.

Et *de* dans le cas contraire.

Ton *couscous de la mer* étant, en ce sens un peu intrus car la mer... n'est évidemment pas un ingrédient. Dans ce cas précis le *de* va indiquer la provenance des ingrédients, on n'a alors évidemment pas le choix... un *couscous à la mer* invitant plus à aller chercher une bouée de sauvetage... ;-)

Comment: j'aurais plutôt eu tendance à dire que `au` insiste plus sur le goût et que `de` insiste plus sur la composition. Mais je me trompe peut-être

Comment: @Flying_whale : Ce n'est pas faux. Dans la mesure ou effectivement, on peut noter que ce sont les ingrédients secondaires qui communiquent un goût particulier. Comme pour un *poulet au curry ou aux morilles ou à la moutarde*. Ta tendance peut donc se justifier mais... par transitivité seulement. ;-) Vous m'avez donné faim! :-)